# How to tell if I'm using a Server Dell PowerEdge 2900 I or II?

Tags: dell-poweredge

How to find out the exact version of this old server? 
It doesn't seem to be any mark or number printed on it (I was looking for a roman numeral).
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service tag is listed in the server's BIOS setup and is likely echoed to the screen during boot.

Additionally, you can get this info by installing OMSA on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the Dell Diagnostics are installed, there may be a way to run the interactively from the start menu or just try running DellSystemInfo.exe from an **Admin** Command Prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\AdvDiags\DSET\bin   DellSystemInfo.exe
```

It should output a zip file with instructions on how to extract and open the report.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://store.flagshiptech.com/dell-poweredge-2900-system-boards-motherboards-generation-differences) indicates that there are three generations of PowerEdge 2900, which can be identified by the motherboard model:

- Gen I: J7551 or TM757
- Gen II: YM158
- Gen III: NX642

The motherboard model can be found by looking up your service tag at http://www.dell.com/support, and going to System configuration -> Components -> Other parts.  One of those model numbers should feature there.